# Tkinter bind callback to activating a window

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm writing a Tkinter application in Python 3 and I've created a custom Title Bar (the bar at the top of every Windows application with the application name, close button etc.). The way I achieved this was to create an invisible window (we'll call this window `test`) that controls the main application window's behavior (which we'll call `Main App`). Below is a piece of test code that illustrates this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Label, Frame, Style


class NewRoot(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 1.0)  # This is normally set to 0.0


class MyMain(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry('750x650+400+600')

        self.style = Style()

        self.style.configure('TTitleBar.Label',
                             width=8,
                             relief='flat',
                             foreground='red',
                             background='red',
                             anchor='center',
                             borderwidth=-1)

        self.style.configure('TMainWindow.Label',
                             width=8,
                             relief='flat',
                             background='blue',
                             anchor='center',
                             borderwidth=-1)

        self.tk_setPalette(background='green')

        self.x_win = None
        self.y_win = None
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None

        # make a frame for the title bar
        title_bar = Frame(self, style='TTitleBar.Label')
        title_bar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wn')

        label = Label(title_bar, text='Main App', style='TMainWindow.Label')
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(4, 2), pady=(4, 0), sticky='nw')

        minimize_button = Button(title_bar, text='MIN', command=self.minimize_window,
                                 style='TMainWindow.Label', takefocus=False)
        minimize_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(563.5, 0), sticky='nw')

        maximise_button = Button(title_bar, text='MAX', command=self.maximize_window,
                                 style='TMainWindow.Label', takefocus=False)
        maximise_button.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=(1.4, 0), sticky='nw')

        close_button = Button(title_bar, text='CLOSE', command=self.close_window,
                              style='TMainWindow.Label', takefocus=False)
        close_button.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nw')

        window = Frame(self)
        window.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ne')

        # bind title bar motion to the move window function
        title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_window)
        title_bar.bind('<Button-1>', self.get_pos)
        self.master.bind("<Map>", self.on_root_deiconify)
        self.master.bind("<Unmap>", self.on_root_iconify)

        self.mainloop()

    def minimize_window(self):
        self.master.iconify()

    def maximize_window(self):
        pass

    def close_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def on_root_iconify(self, event):
        # print('unmap')
        self.withdraw()

    def on_root_deiconify(self, event):
        # print('map')
        self.deiconify()

    def get_pos(self, event):
        self.x_win = self.winfo_x()
        self.y_win = self.winfo_y()
        self.start_x = event.x_root
        self.start_y = event.y_root
        self.y_win = self.y_win - self.start_y
        self.x_win = self.x_win - self.start_x

    def move_window(self, event):
        # print('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root, event.y_root))
        self.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root + self.x_win, event.y_root + self.y_win))

        self.start_x = event.x_root
        self.start_y = event.y_root


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = NewRoot()
    root.title('test')
    app = MyMain(root)
```

In the code above, whenever the `test` window is minimized, the `Main App` window is also minimized, which works as intended.

The problem is that whenever the `test` window  is made active, the `Main App` window doesn't become active also. For example, if another app covers `Main App` but `test` is not minimized, I need to click on the `test` icon in the Windows Task Bar three times for it to appear.

I was wondering if there is a way to fix this using something like:

`self.master.bind(<some_command>, self.some_other_command)`

However, I can't find a comprehensive list of `bind` commands anywhere.
Is this a good way of going about this, or is there something else I should be doing?

Also, I noticed that using `self.overrideredirect(1)` causes the shadows made by the windows to disappear, which causes overlapping windows in my application to 'merge together', since the background colors are the same. Is there a way to add the shadows back?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you define making a window _active_? Also you should lose most of the code to have a [mcve].

Comment: @Nae By 'active' I mean that you click on the icon in the taskbar, and the window should now be the top-most window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this for anyone else with a similar problem. You can create a 'dummy' button in the invisible window that will become active when the window is in focus. You then have that call a function that places the main application window in focus.

```
class NewRoot(Tk):
def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
    entry = Button()
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()
    entry.pack_forget()
```

Then add this to `__init__` in the `MyMain` class:

```
self.master.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_root_deiconify)
```